# How to count Cyrillic characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, counting, cyrillic

I have the following code, but it doesn't work with Cyrillic characters.

```js
      let words = input.value.match(/\b[-?(\w+)?]+\b/gi);
      // console.log(words);
      if (words) {
        wordCount.innerHTML = words.length;
      } else {
        wordCount.innerHTML = 0;
      }
```

Is there a way to match and count Cyrillic chars only?

Comment: Are you trying to match characters in general or is it a Cyrillic only text? You could count all whitespaces and subtract that from the string length

Comment: That is not problem anymore. Now part of  my code cant find top words in Cyrillic text.

Comment: What is your exact problem? I can't really tell from your question, can you please update it and add some examples so we can see exactly what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You may now use Unicode property (or category) classes in JavaScript `RegExp` patterns.

To test if there is a Cyrillic char in a string, use

```
/\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}/u.test(string)
/\p{Script=Cyrl}/u.test(string)
```

See other `Script` and `Script_extension` values in the [ECMAScript documentation](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#table-unicode-script-values), Table 54.

To match all Cyrillic chars as an array of chars, use

```
string.match(/\p{Script=Cyrl}/gu)
```

To get the count, just use

```
string.match(/\p{Script=Cyrl}/gu).length
```

If you need to find Cyrillic char chunk count, use

```
string.match(/\p{Script=Cyrl}+/gu)
```

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const string = 'Name: Драгослав Ивковић';
console.log(/\p{Script=Cyrl}/u.test(string));
// => true, there is at least one Cyrillic
console.log(string.match(/\p{Script=Cyrl}/gu));
// => ["Д","р","а","г","о","с","л","а","в","И","в","к","о","в","и","ћ"]
console.log(string.match(/\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}+/gu));
// => Two chunks found: ["Драгослав","Ивковић"]
console.log(string.match(/\p{Script=Cyrl}/gu).length); // => 16
```